# Using Extra to pass data to a different Activity in Android

Tags: android

I dont know if this is possible to do.  What I have is an activity that has multiple buttons on it.  Each button takes the user to a new activity where the user enters some data (i.e firstName) and a done button that goes back to main activity.  I also have a summary button that will display everything that is entered from the various buttons.  I understand how to pass the data to a new activity, but is there a way to pass the data into a third activity?

****Let me see if I can clarify my question better.  I have 3 activities (A, B, C).  Activity A is my main activity, from A I want to go to Activity B and add some data (like name).  Then in Activity B when I click "Done" button I go back to Activity A.  In activity A i click "summary" button and go to Activity C.  In Activity C I should see a textview with the information I put in Activity B.****

Any help or direction would really help. Thanks.
This is what i have when passing data between two activities as a start:

This button takes you to the a page to enter a name

```
  //button to display event name
    mEventNameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eventNameButton);
    mEventNameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(EventDetails.this, EventName.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

In the EventName activity (1st) here is the code i have for the done button with the extra:

```
     mEventNameDoneButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.eventNameDoneButton);
     mEventNameDoneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(EventName.this, EventDetails.class);
            i.putExtra("eName", mEventNameEditText.getText().toString());
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

and here is the button that is on the EventDetails activity (2nd) for the summary

```
  mEventSummaryButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.eventSummaryButton);
    mEventSummaryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(EventDetails.this, EventSummary.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

finally the code for displaying the extra in the EventSummary activity (3rd).

```
 mResultEventName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultEventName);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String eName =i.getStringExtra("eName");

    //display info
    mResultEventName.setText("Event name has been set: " + eName);
}
```

what i get is the 
"Event name has been set to null"

****Edit****
Here is what I attempted but not understanding how to use the onActivityResult for Activity C.
Updated Code: Activity A

```
      //button to display event name
    mEventNameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eventNameButton);
    mEventNameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(EventDetails.this, EventName.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        }
    });

    //button to display event summary
    mEventSummaryButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.eventSummaryButton);
    mEventSummaryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(EventDetails.this, EventSummary.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });



}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int RequestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (data == 1)
    {
       return;
    }

}
```

}

Actvity B code:

```
//done button to go back to event details
    mEventNameDoneButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.eventNameDoneButton);
    mEventNameDoneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(EventName.this, EventSummary.class);
            i.putExtra("eName", mEventNameEditText.getText().toString());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
            finish();
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Edit for onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int RequestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (data != null)
    {
       final String eventName = data.getStringExtra("ename");
        //button to display event summary
        mEventSummaryButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.eventSummaryButton);
        mEventSummaryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(EventDetails.this, EventSummary.class);
                i.putExtra("ename", eventName.toString());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Your updated question is different. Look up usage on  `startActivityForResult()`

Comment: to confirm: activity A starts activity B. The user enters information in activity B, and clicks done (closing activity B, and revealing activity A, which is open in the background). That information should be returned to activity A, which is then able to pass the information to activity C, via an extra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have not misunderstood, The problem is that you want to show eName inside `EventSummary`, that it is started by `EventDetails`, but the string belongs to the intent that started `EventDetails`. I think that what you are missing, is somehow,

```
Intent i = new Intent(EventDetails.this, EventSummary.class);
i.putExtra("eName", getIntent().getStringExtra("eName"));
startActivity(i);
```

EDIT

I read your update and it actually does change your question. I guess you can use `startActivityForResult` to start  B from A, in order to provide a with the information you want to pass C. To do so, you have to implement `onActivityResult` inside A. When you are done with B, call

```
setResult(int, Intent); 
finish();
```

on B. A's `onActivityResult` will be invoked, and inside its third parameter, the same intent you provide to `setResult`, you can extract the information you need to provide to C

Edit2: 
the code inside the onClickListner should look like:

```
mEventNameDoneButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.eventNameDoneButton);
    mEventNameDoneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.putExtra("eName", mEventNameEditText.getText().toString());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

In Actvity A:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int RequestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (data != null)
    {
       // get eName from data
       // create the new intent to start C
      // add eName
      // start C
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that makes sense.  I updated my code but I guess I'm not understanding how to translate this into code.  I added what I attempted(not complete) and am not sure what to do next.  Any extra help or a sample would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: thank you @blackbelt.  I got it now.  Just need to figure the code to put in the onActivityResult I think I'm close!

Comment: Hi @blackbelt, Sorry one more question,  on the very bottom of my question I added my code to getting the third activity based on the example you provided above.  Will that work?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes it definitely should. You can get rid of to string()

Comment: Thanks, that work now to figure out why I get a null value when enter a name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

```
 mResultEventName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultEventName);

        Intent i = getIntent().getExtras();
        String eName =i.getString("eName");

        //display info
        mResultEventName.setText("Event name has been set: " + eName);
    }
```